# ADFS 2016 OpenId Connect, one asp.net core web app multiple api resources

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, openid-connect, adfs4.0

I have created a asp.net core web application that needs to access multiple APIs. Authentication is supposed to happen through ADFS. I am able to setup OpenId Connect authentication and retrieve the access_token for a single api resource. How can I retrieve access_tokens for the remaining APIs so I can call them or one access_token with multiple audiences?

Normally I should be adding scopes, but it seems ADFS has a different meaning for scopes than IdentityServer and instead uses the "Resource" option.

```
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
        })
        .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.Authority = appSettings.Authority;
            options.ClientId = appSettings.ClientId;
            options.ClientSecret = appSettings.ClientSecret;
            options.SaveTokens = true;

            foreach (var scope in appSettings.Scopes)
            {
                options.Scope.Add(scope);
            }

            options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
            options.Resource = appSettings.TemplateServiceIdentifier;
        });
```

Then I can, when needed to just call

```
    var token = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken);
```

then add the token as bearer and validate it just fine. And this works fine for every single resource (API) if I add it from the start. However I don't seem to be able to obtain access tokens for more than one resource at a time.

Is it even possible with ADFS? 
Should I retrieve one access token for all API resources (since the identity provider is the same for all APIs) with multiple audiences?

Comment: Hi. Have you found a solution to your problem, I've the same to solve. Thanks